# How storm nimbus getting the ACK from a worker? does it use zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

How it's work? does they use zookeeper for that?saves the ACK inside a znode?
I'm trying to build a distributed system using zookeeper, I need to get acknowledge from the various machines in the cluster, 200k ack/sec.

Is it possible to use zookeeper for doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storm doesn't use zookeeper for acking tuples and doesn't send the ack to nimbus. They are sent to the spout directly.

From the [guaranteeing message processing](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html) page:

> A Storm topology has a set of special "acker" tasks that track the DAG
>   of tuples for every spout tuple. When an acker sees that a DAG is
>   complete, it sends a message to the spout task that created the spout
>   tuple to ack the message.

You'll need to override the ack method in your spout:

```
@Override
public void ack(Object id) {
    int number = (Integer)id;
    System.out.println(String.format("Spout ack -> %d", number));
}
```

Comment: How the "acker" tasks get the information from the workers(different machines)?

Comment: @15412s Those questions can get fairly complicated fast.. I think you should ask a new question for each one. :)